# Error downloading and installling ant

Tags: macos, ant, homebrew

Hi i am trying to install ant build system on my mac running latest version of OSX and i get this error:

```
    brew install ant
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz
Error: Failed to download resource "ant"
Download failed: Couldn't determine mirror, try again later.
```

Not sure what the issue is as all examples i have seen stated that the above should work fine?

i even tried a brew update and still get the same error.

Any suggestions?